# print keys and value of of php multidiamensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am php beginner. I have a multidimensional array as follows.

```
$mainArray = array();

$mainArray['apple'] = array();
$mainArray['apple'][0] = 'fruit';
$mainArray['apple'][1] = 'red';

$mainArray['banana'] = array();
$mainArray['banana'][0] = 'fruit';
$mainArray['banana'][1] = 'yellow';

$mainArray['spinach'] = array();
$mainArray['spinach'][0] = 'vegetable';
$mainArray['spinach'][1] = 'green';
```

I want to get an output as follows:

```
apple is fruit
apple is red
banana is fruit
banana is yellow
spinach is vegetable
spinach is green
```

I am struggling to use a `for` or `foreach` loop in PHP to find the first key which is `apple, banana or spinach`.. any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: Is the order in the output important, and if yes why banana first? Also include your current attempt into your question.

Comment: with a foreach you can specify both a key and value variable. `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` and the `$key` will have the key and `$value` will have the value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($mainArray as $type => $descriptions) {
    foreach ($descriptions as $description) {
        echo $type . ' is ' . $description, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

If you need to output them in a specific order, sort your array before using something simple like the above example.

Comment: Awesome! I cant believe I spent so much time on this. Thank you so much!